# List with type constraints on consecutive elements

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is it possible to define a list type where every pair of consecutive elements satisfies some relation (constraint). For example, a list of functions such that the functions can be composed:

```
val f1: A => B = ???
val f2: B => C = ???
val f3: C => D = ???

type SafeList = ??? // how to define this?

val fs: SafeList = f1 :: f2 :: f3 :: HNil // OK

val fs: SafeList = f1 :: f3 :: HNil       // ERROR
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not usually possible to describe interesting constraints like this using a type alias—instead you want a type class that will serve as evidence that a type has some property.

With Shapeless it's often possible to accomplish this using type classes that the library provides, but I don't think that's the case here. Fortunately it's not too hard to write your own:

```
import shapeless._

// Evidence that an hlist is made up of functions that can be composed.
trait Composable[L <: HList] {
  type In
}

object Composable {
  type Aux[L <: HList, In0] = Composable[L] { type In = In0 }

  implicit def composable0[A, B]: Aux[(A => B) :: HNil, A] =
    new Composable[(A => B) :: HNil] {
      type In = A
    }

  implicit def composable1[A, B, T <: HList]
    (implicit tc: Aux[T, B]): Aux[(A => B) :: T, A] =
      new Composable[(A => B) :: T] {
        type In = A
      }
}

def composable[L <: HList: Composable] {}
```

What we're doing here is describing how to build up evidence inductively, with a singleton `HList` as the base case. At each step we use the `In` type member to keep track of what the output type of the next (i.e. earlier in the list) function must be.

And to confirm that it does what we expect:

```
scala> composable[(Int => String) :: (String => Char) :: HNil]

scala> composable[(Int => Long) :: (Long => Char) :: (Char => String) :: HNil]

scala> composable[(Int => String) :: (Symbol => Char) :: HNil]
<console>:23: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter...
```

The first two work just fine, while the third doesn't compile.

Comment: Answer that works and is educative. Thanks! Interestingly enough, your example works even when I replace the bodies of `composable0` and `composable1` with `null`. However, I will need the typeclass instance when I try to actually do something with the list that exploits the composability, which I will have to do through typeclass methods, I suppose.

Comment: That's right—note in this case you'll probably also need to add an `Out` type member to do anything useful apart from provide evidence that the types line up.